# visual studio 2008 side-by-side problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I made an app built it in debug mode and want to run in on another machine.
There is an error:

the application failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect

What are possible solutions for that?

I need to have debug version

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

1. Copy the debug redistributable, which is inside `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86`. Take all the directories there and put them in your application's folder.
2. Configure your project to link statically to the runtime.